# Read CSV file in a Shell Script till End Of Line Without Header

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have a file called as 'readfile.csv' with following contents.

```
Name    Id        VAl       Number    IP
James,007,$500,111-111-111,111-000-000
Bond,700,$900,100-000-999, 666-999-000
```

Here `Name, Id, Val, Number and IP` are heading in the csv file and the second line i.e., `FirstVal, SecondVal` etc are the values of those headers. I want to read only the values and not headers and display it in console. How do I do it? And also I want to read values till end of line/end of file as I don't know how many columns can be present in the file. It can be 5 or 6 columns.

Right now I am able to read a single line without header as below in shell script. But this does not help my condition mentioned here.

```
#!/bin/bash

val1=( $(cut -d ',' -f1 readfile.csv ) )
printf "%s\n" "${val1[0]}"
val2=( $(cut -d ',' -f2 readfile.csv ) )
printf "%s\n" "${val2[0]}"
val3=( $(cut -d ',' -f3 readfile.csv ) )
printf "%s\n" "${val3[0]}"
```

I actually want to append these values to other script. For example, I have a script called as runfile.sh which appends the values from the awk and opens a file location through http.

Example, 'runfile.sh' is storing this value:

```
'https://my_win_loc/personinfo'
```

Now runfile will read the csv file and append each value to this url, like this:

```
'https://my_win_loc/personinfo/James'
'https://my_win_loc/personinfo/Bond'
```

Please help me in resolving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use `Awk` for these kind of tasks which is *ideal*. Read more about the variables `FS`,`OFS`,`FNR`, `NR` and `NF` from this [built-in variables in `Awk` page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/User_002dmodified.html#User_002dmodified) before proceeding further.

`Awk` in general processes one line at a time tracked by the variable `NR`, so skip the header line using `NR>1` i.e. meaning, skipping line `NR==1`,

The variables `FS` and `OFS` define how your input and output lines are de-limited. Since you are working with a `.csv` file, it would be wise to set it to `,`. Once this is done as part of `BEGIN{}` clause (executed before processing of the file happens), the individual fields can be printed from `$1`..`$NF` where `NF` is the max number of fields separated by the `FS` in each line.

so,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' input.csv
```

---

Answer updated to match OP's requirement,

```
awk -v str="https://my_win_loc/personinfo" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>1 {print str"/"$1}' input.csv
```

Comment: Thank you Inian. On executing the above mentioned awk line, I am getting output with the header.
Name    Id        VAl       Number    IP

.The values I can store on new line but still header is visible

Comment: @Raji: Sorry it was a mistake, missed adding `NR>1` in the command. Try it now

Comment: @Raji: This prints each element in a separate line (excluding header). How would you like to print it? Can you show an example?

Comment: Thanks a lot Inian. The header went away with the modified line. I want to display code as follows in new line:
val1:FirstVal
Val2:SecondVal

Comment: the above mentioned are all in new line. I am not able to edit comments to put in new line

Comment: Hi Inian. I have updated the main description. Please have a check

Comment: @Raji: Sorry! The given information is not helping. provide some sample lines from your `.csv` file and from it show the information you are trying to generate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144250/discussion-between-raji-and-inian).

Comment: I have updated it again with possible actual value. I cannot update the actual value as data is important

Comment: @Raji: Refer my updated answer, let me know if this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, this sort of thing is done either with `awk` or with a simple `read` loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec < readfile.csv || exit 1
read header # read (and ignore) the first line
while IFS=, read name id val number ip; do
    echo name = "$name"
    echo id = "$id"
    echo val = "$val"
    echo number = "$number"
    test -n "$ip" && echo ip = "$ip"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard `awk` library can be used for that purpose. To exclude header line, you can

```
awk '{if (NR!=1) {print}}' readfile.csv
```

Here **NR is the number of lines**.

Comment: Hi Bilalsamioguz. Thank you for the response. The code works fine but displays output with comma.  Inian helped in fixing the code.